# Load image in Javafx from external resource

Tags: java, resources, javafx

I would like to load an image from a directory (external to Jar file) i.e. `/Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/backgroundBlue-Wallpaper.jpg` using javafx, however no image gets loaded. 
I guess because the code below would get the image from the inside the jar file

Any help please

```
images = new ArrayList<String>();
directory = new File("/Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/background/");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for(File f : files) {images.add(f.getName());}   
System.out.println(images);
int countImages = images.size();

int imageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * countImages);
rand_Image_Path = directory + images.get(imageNumber);

String image = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource(rand_Image_Path).toExternalForm(); 
Mainpane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-image-repeat: repeat; -fx-background-size: 1080 1920;-fx-background-position: bottom left;");
```

Comment: Try using new File(rand_Image_path).toURI().toURL().toString()

Comment: you mean like this: try
        {
        String image = new File(rand_Image_Path).toURI().toURL().toString();
//        String image = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource(rand_Image_Path).toExternalForm();
//        Mainpane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-repeat: repeat; ");  
        Mainpane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-image-repeat: repeat; -fx-background-size: 1080 1920;-fx-background-position: bottom left;");        
        }
        catch (IOException e) {logger.warn("Unexpected error", e);}

Comment: Nope, don't use JavaFXApplication, just File#toURI#toURL

Comment: sorry, but this is what i used, but still get null exception

Comment: try
        {
        String image = new File(rand_Image_Path).toURI().toURL().toString();
        Mainpane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-image-repeat: repeat; -fx-background-size: 1080 1920;-fx-background-position: bottom left;");        
        }
        catch (IOException e) {logger.warn("Unexpected error", e);}

Comment: What is the result of `new File(rand_Image_Path).toURI().toURL().toString()`, try printing it to the console to make sure you have a valid reference to the file

Comment: image string: /Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/backgroundgreen-wallpaper.jpg

Comment: That's wrong, it should look more like `file:/C:/hold/thumbnails/_cg_836___Tilting_Windmills___by_Serena_Clearwater.png`.  I use this to load images when formatting html `String`s in Swing

Comment: strange, although this is linux machine, wonder why file is not appended

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i am getting this: image string: file:/Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/backgroundgreen-wallpaper.jpg

Comment: the background is funny though, it's like garbage/ scramled image

Comment: Are you able to provide a simple runnable example?

Comment: hard to do, but will try

Comment: Just needs to provide a single image support which I can update manually

Comment: I found the error, I was acctually getting this as the file string /Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/backgroundgreen-wallpaper.jpg where as it should be /Users/ossama/Projects/Pi/javafx/prayertime/background/green-wallpaper.jpg missing "/"

Comment: lol, such simple things ;)

Comment: silly things.........